# Trying to perform a calculation in an expression but returning error with syntax

Tags: javascript, json, string

You will have to bear with me as my knowledge on this subject is very very limited and most of this information was provided to me by external development sources.

We are trying to build a workflow that triggers on a specific figure from a sales order - The margin % by line and will activate based on a set threshold by ourselves.

We have been given the following :

```
$.response.tOutoeordline.t-outoeordline[?(((@.netamt-@.scrncost)///@.scrncost)<0.25)].lineno
```

But this is giving us an error:

> Step GetOrderDetails[0] failed: Error handling output parameter 'MarginLine'; Expected character: )

We have tried a number of different variations but having no real knowledge of how it should be formatted I'm at a loss.

The calculation we are looking to achieve is Netamt - Scrncost / Scrncost and for it to trigger if this result is below 0.25 on any line.

Could anyone shed any light on this (again apologies if my description isn't great, if you need further information from me please let me know)?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: There is no visible connection between the line you posted and the error you show

Comment: There's a bunch of issues here; `//` indicates the start of a comment (see the code highlighting of the line in your question), but even if I replace the `///` with a `/` there's still the issues of the `?` and `@`. This isn't valid JavaScript, so please give more context. Additionally, the inner expression can be replaced with `netamt / scrncost < 1.25`, however the result will be a boolean and I'm not sure you can use that as key for an array or object.